# How can I use a formula in my function?

Tags: r

I apologize if this question is trivial or a duplicate but I can't find any answers anywhere. I've read the docs and similar questions here but they aren't answering my question. My background is in nonstatistical programming in languages like javascript, python etc so please explain for that audience.

My question is simple (hopefully):

**What is a formula? What is the `~` operator? How are they evaluated and used?**

(As someone with a programming background,) I want to understand formulas like I understand any other type: what operations can I perform on them and how can I use them generically in functions?

For example, the mosaic package (from `library(mdsr)`) has the `mean` function.

```
mean( ~ mpg, data = mtcars)
```

They are using the `~` operator to grab the column name. I know that the `$` operator as in `mtcars$mpg` returns a vector of all the `mpg`s within the data frame `mtcars`. How can I use a formula to make generic functions like that? **How can I evaluate the formula?** How does that type work?

Comment: you can create a function the same way you would in python, by defining it with a name, adding inputs and setting default values and then building the internal equation from scratch using typical r notation. It does not have to be structured like your example. If you were to show a sample of data and a simple equation, I would be happy to create a simple example.

Comment: @bethanyP i know how to define a function in R, i'm more confused on how to use a formulas